# Can I load a cross-domain CSS file as a text string using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-domain

I am running a javascript environment at x.y.com, but I need to read to content of a css file at a.b.com.  Is there any way to make an ajax call to load the content of this file as a text string?  Does doing this violate the "spirit" of the Same-Origin policy on various browsers?  Basically, I'm trying to compile a list of ALL the CSS Rules affecting a page, even those loaded from cross-origin external css files (whose rules are not shown in `document.styleSheets[x].cssRules[]`).

Comment: It does violate the spirit and the letter of the Same Origin policy, yes... but are you sure those style sheets don't show up in `document.styleSheets` when loaded the normal way? That would be strange.

Comment: They do not - cross-origin CSS Rules are not listed in 'document.styleSheets'

Comment: You can load the contents of the file via CORS or JSONP.  Both require cooperation from the remote server.  Or, you could proxy the file from your local server.

Comment: Sadly, this is a content script that I am running on top of an existing page I don't control, so I have no control over the remote hosting of these files and proxying is out of the question.

Comment: Then there is no way for you to request and read these cross-domain files in the browser.